# Nginx Proxy Pass Not Working

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Firstly, deployed my node application on port 8080. It is working successfully. Then I installed nginx.

Here is my example.com file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder. My Node application work on 8080 port so I am using proxy_pass.

```
server {

        listen 80;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;

        }

}
```

When I try to access my application with ip addr and port like this;

```
1.1.1.1:8080
```

I can successfully access my application, everything going well.

Lastly, I want to connect my `example.com` domain to My Node application that work on 8080 port. So I create DNS like that;

| Type | Content | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | example.com | 1.1.1.1 |

But when I go my domain I'm seeing; `Welcome to nginx!` (default) page. It's mean my domain not connecting to **8080** port, just using **80** port because when I go my ip addr with **80** port I'm seeing this page too.

Why is not working?

Comment: `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`? They are different.

Comment: @LexLi ; I do not understand well. I'm using ssl on domain so `https://example.com`. Should I use it instead of `example(xxx).com` ?

Comment: There are steps missing from your description. Did you verify the config? Did you reload the config? Did you check the nginx logs?

Comment: @symcbean; this is my file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder.

Comment: So no, no and no. Maybe you you should try these steps.

Comment: @symcbean which steps? Where is my mistake?

Comment: The steps in my comment - I can't give you the commands to use because you didn't tell us anything about how this was provisioned.

Comment: @symcbean I try to give more detail, can you check my question again?

Comment: i bet your http requests is not going to the backend that you are proxying.
check you app access logs in localhost:8080.

when you see page "Welcome to nginx!" it's possible that your nginx is not serving your vhost well (server_name example.com), it should be server by another config (default nginx config).

check in your nginx.conf if it's already include `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder, sometimes it just don't include it, and your vhosts config is not loaded, then all requests will go to default nginx page.

Comment: When you browse to `https://example.com`, your HTTP requests go to port 443 and they will not arrive at the Node.js web app you set up (and the default page is served as expected). You have to browse to `http://example.com` to reach port 80. If you do want port 443 to work, revise your nginx config file to include that.